# Linear Interpolation in image processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am going through a paper in computer vision, and I came through this line :

`the L values, or the luminance values, for these pixels are then linearly and horizontally interpolated between the pixels on the (one pixel wide) brightest column in region B, and the pixels in regions A and C.`

What does linear and horizontal interpolation mean?

So I tried looking for linear interpolation, so does it mean that we average out the values of pixels which are linear to each other? As I can't see any proper definition.

Paper : http://140.118.9.222/publications/journal/haircut.pdf

Comment: You may be better off emailing the authors.

Comment: If I had to guess I believe they are saying that they perform linear interpolation on the luminescence values in the horizontal direction, as opposed to something like bilinear interpolation

Comment: @jodag I think linear interpolation is something common right. Any idea what it is?

found this  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Comment: @arqam that's why programmers have to know their maths... image-processing is 100% maths. you are manipulating and analyzing discrete 2d functions, in case you haven't noticed.

Comment: Oh I thought you were just confused by the wording. Linear interpolation is a very common and intuitive way to fill in gaps between data points. It is something anyone doing any form of signal processing should be very familiar with.

Comment: @jodag So in this case if we are interpolating between two points then the value of L for pixels in between should be filled using the formula : `(x-x0)/(x1-x0)`?

Comment: @arqam No. If `x0` and `x1` are the horizontal positions of the endpoints and `y0`, `y1` are the luminance values, then the luminance value `y` at any in between location `x` is `y=y0+(x-x0)*(y1-y0)/(x1-x0)`

Comment: @jodag, thanks. Double checked from your comment. Was using the right formula.

Answer (score 3):

Every programmer should know linear interpolation!!! Especially if you're entering the domain of image-processing.

Please read this and never ever forget about it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

The paper describes pretty well what is going on. They synthesize skin texture by sampling the face and then interpolating between those samples. They sample 3 regions A, B and C.

They pick the brightest column of B, the left-most column of A and the right-most column of C.

Then for every row they linearly interpolate between the columns' pixels.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, means a lot.
Can you please explain this line a bit : 
`Then for every row they linearly interpolate between the columns' pixels.`

Comment: @arqam just read the wikipedia article. I won't teach you linear interpolation here... they have 3 L values per row and the L values between those points are obtained by linear interpolation between those values.

Comment: Yeah I read the article and understood linear interpolation.
I am trying to understand the context, so that means that for a particular row, like in this case we have 3 points, and we draw a line connecting these points and the value in between these points should be got using `(x-x0)/(x1-x0)` ?

Comment: @arqam you draw 2 lines. one between A and B and one between B and C. The synthetic points are on these lines.

Comment: So, in linear interpolation the value is heavily decided by the two end points that we take right?

Comment: Using this formula only right : `(x-x0)/(x1-x0)`, where x0 and x1 are the two end points X value.

Comment: Do you know how can we apply the texture got in the image region if we have the contour points. As shown in `Fig 7c & Fig 7e` in the paper.